# Differences between paraphrase and rephrase

Tags: theoretical-linguistics

What differences are between paraphrase and rephrase?

Do they both retain the  meaning of the original text, and not add new information?

Do they both have similar length as the original text?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is the right site for the question.

This is my understanding, as a non native English speaker. :-)
I am answering because I am interested in comments.

I think the major difference is that rephrasing occurs in the same
discourse usually to improve understanding or precision of meaning. It
is not necessarily done at the same time, or by the same person.

Paraphrasing is usually done by another person, who is somehow
appropriating the phrase (even though she may quote the original
author), possibly for a different context or different discourse.
One can paraphrase herself when quoting herself in a different
context, hence adapting meaning.

I would think the length does not change too much in either case.

I would think that rephrasing tries to preserve or improve meaning, hence can add new information,
while paraphrasing can adapt it, thus modifying the information.

Comment: This sounds mostly correct.  I would add: I would use "rephrase" in the context of "I didn't understand that, please re-phrase" or "I don't think that's what you meant, please re-phrase".  I would use paraphrase _usually_ if I was repeating the sentence, but didn't remember (or didn't want to use) the exact wording (ie "I paraphrase Abraham Lincoln: " instead of "I quote Abraham Lincoln")